# Catch a parameter error within a function?

Tags: ruby

Is it possible for a method to handle an error that happens in a parameter?

e.g.

```
def add(arg1, arg2)
    # If the value causes an error, turn it into 0
    rescue nil
        0
    end
    arg1 + arg2
end

add(2, 2+nil) => 2
```

I understand that shielding parameters and eval-ing it later can be a solution, but in my scenario it becomes too cumbersome to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with this is the error occurs on the line where you provide the arguments as arguments are evaluated *prior* to the method being called.

Every method call is roughly equivalent to this:

```
arg1 = 2
arg2 = 2 + nil

add(arg1, arg2)
```

In this case you can see how the argument itself produces an error. The only way to defer the evaluation of an argument is via a block:

```
add(2) do
  2 + nil
end
```

Changing your definition to:

```
def add(v)
  v + yield

rescue
  v + 0
end
```

Capturing *all* exceptions blindly is usually a super bad plan, you may have some kind of fundamental mistake in there. It's best to avoid capturing exceptions unless you have expectations as to what kind they will be.

Here's a version of the method with no exception handling:

```
def add(*args)
  args.map(&:to_i).inject(:+)
end
```

Now `nil.to_i` returns `0` so you're covered:

```
add(2,2,nil)
```

That will evaluate to `2+2+0` internally.

Generally it's a bad plan to try and bury errors like `2+nil`. That's a fundamental mistake that should be addressed. If you wanted to handle `nil` values you would use `.to_i` to map them down to something usable.

Comment: ...or just remove the `nil`s first: `args.compact.inject(:+)`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland True, if you add `.to_i` on the end to capture the case with all `nil`.

Comment: ...or `[nil, nil].compact.inject(0, :+) #=> 0`.

Answer (score 0):

In this case your add method isn't still called and you have to rescue in the caller.